# com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.api gateway.Api Clientexception invalid login token

Tags: amazon-web-services, auth0

[image]

`com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.api gateway.Api Clientexception invalid login token` while using auth0. This was working fine some time back.

Comment: Auth0 Dev here, this seems to be a configuration issue on your backend, can you check if the the URL provided for the Identity Provider is correct? One reason that this might change is adding custom domains

Comment: There are two likely reasons for the downvote storm: [an error message supplied as an image](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/), and urgent begging so egregious it was essentially vandalism.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1):

Auth0 seems to have changed the certificate for *.auth0.com the new thumbprint is 
f301d61981fd59a3271d0b8a8412448f500e0f86

old was:

02faf3e291435468607857694df5e45b68851868

You just need to add it in IAM > Identity providers > Thumbprint